# How to rectify issues occurring while installing Cufflinks and Boost?

Tags: macos, boost, bioinformatics

I'm having a problem installing [Cufflinks](http://cufflinks.cbcb.umd.edu/).  Before installing Cufflinks, I installed Boost first with:

```
bjam --prefix=/Users/jimmy/Downloads/boost_1_46_1/ toolset=gcc link=static install
```

It seems to be ok.

However, when installing Cufflinks, it seems there is a problem in the installation of Boost. See error below:

```
checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.7/site-packages
checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python2.7/site-packages
checking for boostlib >= 1.38.0... configure: error: We could not detect the boost libraries (version 1.38 or higher). If you have a staged boost library (still not installed) please specify $BOOST_ROOT in your environment and do not give a PATH to --with-boost option.  If you are sure you have boost installed, then check your version number looking in <boost/version.hpp>. See http://randspringer.de/boost for more documentation.
dhcp128036164110:cufflinks-1.0.3 jimmy$ ./configure --prefix=/Users/jimmy/Downloads/ --with-boost=/Users/jimmy/Downloads/boost_1_46_1/
```

If I missed something, could you tell me what is wrong now? Thanks.

PS: I am using Mac OS X (not Windows)

Comment: Have you tried setting `$BOOST_ROOT` instead of passing `--with-boost`?

Comment: how to set up $BOOST_ROOT?? even it is a problem, cufflinks, cuffcompre, cuffdiff, all of them are running well. a bit strange.

Comment: It's just an environment variable -- set it to the root path of your Boost installation (`/Users/jimmy/Downloads/boost_1_46_1` by the looks of it).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578499/boost-installation-ubuntu

check for libboost-all-dev installation

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete procedure I used for installing Cufflinks from source on a Linux Redhat 64-bit system without root privileges.

**Install Boost**

1. Create a directory to install into

`mkdir ~/bin/boost_1_55_0`

2. Download Boost

`wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.55.0/boost_1_55_0.tar.gz`

3. Unpack Boost

`tar xzvf boost_1_55_0.tar.gz`

4. Change into boost directory

`cd boost_1_55_0`

5. Run bootstrap.sh script

`./bootstrap.sh`

6. Run b2 script

`./b2`

7. Run b2 script again to install

`./b2 install –prefix=/lustre/home/jernest1/bin/boost_1_55_0`

8. Add installation directory to several environment variables in ~/.bashrc

Add /lustre/home/jernest1/bin/boost_1_55_0/lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Add /lustre/home/jernest1/boost_1_55_0 to a new variable BOOST_ROOT

Add /lustre/home/jernest1/boost_1_55_0 to a new variable CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH

9. Source ~/.bashrc

`source .bashrc`

**Install SAM tools**

1. Download sam tools

`wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/samtools/files/samtools/0.1.17/samtools-0.1.17.tar.bz2`

2. Unpack

`tar jxvf samtools-0.1.17.tar.bz2`

3. Move into the samtools directory

`cd samtools-0.1.17`

4. Run make

`make`

5. Make new directories to put sam library files if they don’t already exist

`mkdir –p ~/bin/lib`

`mkdir –p ~/bin/include/bam`

6. Copy the libbam.a file to ~/bin/lib/

`cp libbam.a ~/bin/lib/`

7. Copy header files into ~/bin/include/bam/

`cp *.h ~/bin/include/bam/`

 
8. Copy the samtools executable program to a directory in your PATH

`cp samtools ~/bin/`

9. Add the bam directory to the new variable BAM_ROOT in ~/.bashrc

**Install Eigen libraries**

1. Download Eigen libraries

`wget http://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/3.2.3.tar.gz`

2. Unpack

`tar xzvf 3.2.3.tar.gz`

3. Move into Eigen directory

`cd eigen-eigen-36fd1ba04c12`

4. Copy the Eigen subdirectory into ~/bin/include/

`cp -r eigen-eigen-36fd1ba04c12/Eigen/ ~/bin/include/`

**Install Cufflinks**

**Option 1: Install an official release**

1. Make a directory to hold the installation.

`mkdir cufflinks_2.2.1`

2. Move into that directory
`cd cufflinks_2.2.1`

3. Download cufflinks

`wget http://cole-trapnell-lab.github.io/cufflinks/assets/downloads/cufflinks-2.2.1.tar.gz`

4. Unpack

`tar xzvf cufflinks-2.2.1.tar.gz`

`cd cufflinks-2.2.1`

5. Run configure script

`./configure --prefix=/lustre/home/jernest1/cufflinks_2.2.1 --with-eigen=/lustre/home/jernest1/eigen-eigen-36fd1ba04c12/Eigen --with-bam=/lustre/home/jernest1/bin --with-boost=/lustre/home/jernest1/bin/boost_1_55_0`

6. Run make

`make`

7. Run make install

`make install` 

Optionally, copy ~/cufflinks_2.2.1/bin/cufflinks into ~/bin/

**Option 2: install from Github project**

1. Make directory to install into

`mkdir cufflinks_2014-12-11`

2. Move into that directory

`cd cufflinks_2014-12-11`

2. Download Github project

Click on the "HTTPS clone URL" button to save the URL location to your clipboard

Download

`git clone https://github.com/cole-trapnell-lab/cufflinks.git`

4. Run autogen.sh to convert configure.ac into configure

`./autogen.sh`

5. Run configure script

`./configure --prefix=/lustre/home/jernest1/cufflinks_2014-12-11 --with-eigen=/lustre/home/jernest1/eigen-eigen-36fd1ba04c12/Eigen --with-bam=/lustre/home/jernest1/bin --with-boost=/lustre/home/jernest1/bin/boost_1_55_0`

6. Run make

`make`

7. Run make install

`make install` 

Optionally, copy ~/cufflinks_2014-12-11/bin/cufflinks into ~/bin/